# Why not i'm able to use sout Within returning?

Tags: java

```
 int sum(int a,int b) 
     {
         Scanner S1= new Scanner(System.in);
         throw  new ArithmeticException ( "Error");
         System.out.println("Enter   Any  Two Number" );// why Not i'm able to Use  This line while returning .
         a=S1.nextInt();
         b=S1.nextInt();
         return a+b;       

     }
```

Comment: This seems like a very misleading method.  I would expect a method with that signature to just accept two integers and sum them.  I would *not* expect I/O from such a method.  (And I certainly wouldn't expect an exception to be thrown every time it's called.)

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception before that line?

Comment: When you throw an exception, kind of like `return`, you are giving back the control flow to the caller. So that's why you can't have code after `throw`s, just like you can't after `return`s.

Answer (score 3):

You are throwing an exception `throw  new ArithmeticException ( "Error");` before `System.out.println()`. It never reached the `System.out.println` part of your code.

Comment: Just FYI, I fixed an errant apostrophe in place of the backtick.

Answer (score 3):

The `throw` statement unconditionally terminates execution of the method, which means the following lines will never be reached. Java doesn't allow unreachable code of this sort. ([JLS § 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21))